# :focus don't work in PyQt (QT 5.7)

Tags: qt, focus, pyqt5

The following code displays QSS-styled widget on BeagleBone. The style uses :focus specifier which doesn't seem to work. The widget is displayed in red. If I replace :focus with :enabled, the widget is displayed in green.

How to make :focus selector work?

If I replace QSlider with QCheckBox, setting :focus style does not work either, so I believe the problem is not related to the particular widget.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QSlider


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QSlider()
    w.resize(50, 200)
    w.move(30, 30)
    w.setStyleSheet('QSlider { background: red; } QSlider:focus { background: green; }')
    w.setFocus()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[1] Same problem here with no Python involved, http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/27580-how-to-set-focus-on-widget-if-it-is-selected

Comment: Works fine for me on arch-linux (Qt-5.8.0, PyQt-5.7.1).

Comment: Works for me on Cygwin either. It seems the problem is somewhere in Qt/PyQt installation/configuration.

Also focus in/out events are not registered by eventFilter handler, though focused controls somehow work.